# Microsoft Graph API Java - get group using displayName

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using Microsoft Graph API( java SDK) to add members to the group. But I see that I could only pull a group using the "id" .But there should be an easy way to pull the group information using name or displayName? I am trying to get the group id, so that I could use it to add members

`Group group = graphClient.groups("id")
    .buildRequest()
    .get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
LinkedList<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<Option>();
requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$filter", "startswith(displayName, 'Hello')"));

IGroupCollectionPage groups = graphClient.groups()
    .buildRequest(requestOptions)
    .get();
```

This should filter all groups with "displayName" starting with "Hello".

Comment: Yes, this gets the groups. My question is specific to how can I get the Id of that group? If I would like to print the Id of that group?

Comment: I figured it out to get the id. Thank you for the help

Comment: Do you know how to modify to search with exact string name instead of Startswith?

Comment: Yes. Check this doc out for $filter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters  You have a variation of filters with "equals", "not equals"etc. You can also use $select to get only certain properties, or things like $count. Note that not all properties supporta odata filtering.