# Microsoft Graph Java API - Filter Groups based on a boolean value

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to filter the groups using java sdk based on the parameters like mailEnabled or securityEnabled.

I am trying out the following code to perform the same as suggested in the Graph Explorer interface. (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

LinkedList requestOptions = new LinkedList();
requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$filter", "mailEnabled+eq+true"));

IGroupCollectionPage groups = graphClient.groups()
.buildRequest(requestOptions)
.get();

But this throws an exceptio saying that "Invalid filter"

I can filter out the groups using the "startsWith" paramter as mentioned in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417041/microsoft-graph-api-java-get-group-using-displayname"

Looks like there is some issue with + sign here.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please use this way `List<Option> requestOptions = new ArrayList<Option>();
  requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$filter", "mailEnabled eq true"));
  IGroupCollectionPage data = graphClient.groups().buildRequest(requestOptions).get();` There is no need of '+'. This gives you the right results.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Thank You!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below code to get a filtered data for mailEnabled property.

```
List<Option> requestOptions = new ArrayList<Option>();      
requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$filter", "mailEnabled eq true"));       
IGroupCollectionPage data = graphClient.groups()
                            .buildRequest(requestOptions)
                            .get();
```